# Is there a way to get the lead time from Estimate to Completion in Azure DevOps Dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, analytics, dashboard, estimation

I've been using Azure DevOps Dashboard for a while now and it's working nicely. One gap I have found is in it's Lead Time Chart. This goes from date creation to date completed, which in an Agile world doesn't make sense.
Backlogs can be thought of a placeholder for a conversation, following this initial backlogs can be vague and poorly defined, and more information and clarity will be added as the backlog moves closer to being actionable.

What I would want is a "Estimated to Completion". SCRUM teams estimate when there is enough information that the item could be pulled in to a Sprint, and this is the point where the lead time really makes sense.

Is it possible to add this to the DevOps dashboard, is there a query that will give me what I need?

Thanks,

John